# I cants understand the syntax of this picture

Tags: c++

This is a basic program of class. How we will be able to know when to write that data member twice? Here, the student is a data member.

```
Student Student::setRollNo(int aNo)
{
...
return *this;
}
Student Student::setName(char *aName)
{
...
return *this;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Post code as text, not an image. What is the question? `Student` is not a data member in the posted image.

Comment: code should be included in the question as text and then your question is not clear. "student is data member" ... member of what? The two functions seem to be methods of a `Student` class, "write that data member twice?" ... write what twice?

Comment: this seems to be an example for something explained before, did you also look at the preivous slides ?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 It might be referring to the fact that in the declaration `Student Student::whatever`, the name `Student` appears twice consecutively.

Comment: @Angew yes I thought about that, but when in doubt I prefer to clear up the misunderstanding first, could also be that "twice" refers to the two methods

Comment: The parentheses tell you that each of these is a function. Each of these functions has a body, so these are function definitions. A function always has a name and a return type: `int get_value() { return 3; }`. A member function has the name of its class as part of its name: `int Student::get_id() { return id; }`. A function can return any type; in this case, both functions return an object of type `Student`, which is why you see `Student` twice in each definition.

Comment: i am sorry i am new. ..its class program

Comment: What is a class program?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and clarify your question. `Student` is not a data member. It's the name of the class.

Answer (score 1):

`Student` is a type, not a data member, and `setName` is a member function of `Student`.

You have a class definition somewhere along the lines of

```
class Student
{
public: 
    //...
    Student setName(char* aName);
private:
    // ...
};
```

In

```
Student Student::setName(char *aName)
```

the first "Student" is the function's return type, the same as in the declaration of the member function in the class definition; the second "Student" specifies the class whose member function you're defining.

It has exactly the same form as if you had

```
class Student
{
public: 
    //...
    int setName(char* aName);
private:
    // ...
};

int Student::setName(char *aName)
// ...
```